# How to fix 2160p mkv video not running in Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

In my video player when i try to play 2160p MKV 4k video file in exoplayer. The video is not playing.

Error message is ERROR_CODE_DECODING_FAILED
Error code is 4003.
Exoplayer version is 2.16.1

Same video file is playing using android video library and other video player app that i downloaded from play store.

Code :

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getApplicationContext());
    ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this);
    builder = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setSeekBackIncrementMs(10000);
    builder.setSeekForwardIncrementMs(10000);
    player = builder.setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSource).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();//new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    MediaItem mediaItem;
    ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vdList.size(); i++) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(vdList.get(i).path);
        mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(uri).build();
        mediaItems.add(mediaItem);
    }

    player.addMediaItems(mediaItems);
    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    playerView.requestFocus();
    player.prepare();
    player.seekTo(position, C.TIME_UNSET);
    player.play();
```

Please help me out.

Comment: @ Manchu, Even I'm phasing the same issue are you able to resolve it

Comment: Similar error - ExoPlayer error: what=ERROR_CODE_DECODING_FAILED MediaCodecAudioRenderer error, index=1, format=Format(null, null, null, audio/vorbis, null, 32000, null, [-1, -1, -1.0], [2, 44100]), format_supported=YES